# What is the skill Naruto used in the last movie?

Tags: naruto

I just want to know whether there is a specific technique name when Naruto's hand glowed when he took the ball of light out of Hinata. It was also used to attack Toneri Otsutsuki.

I don't watch the anime; I read the manga so I could have missed a lot of stuffs from the fillers. Heck, I don't even know what they show in the filler episodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That technique which Naruto used has no special name, not even at [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Toneri_%C5%8Ctsutsuki).
It is stated that :

> Toneri took Hinata to the Room of Rebirth, letting his puppets to deal
>   with Naruto. As they arrived at the Room of Rebirth and Naruto went
>   after them, Toneri controlled Hinata to attack Naruto only for him to
>   render her unconscious by taking the green chakra sphere out of her
>   body. *After Naruto took out the green sphere*, Toneri took her back
>   from Naruto.......

However, the technique which Toneri Ōtsutsuki used, it is called *Puppet Cursing Sphere*.
It can control, read minds and also has other functions.
It is also mentioned at [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Puppet-Cursing_Sphere) article on Toneri Ōtsutsuki :

> Toneri moulds his chakra into the form of a green-coloured sphere. The
>   sphere can be used various purposes such as controlling targets by
>   sending it into their body, reading their minds, absorbing chakra from
>   a distance, checking if a target has a dormant Ōtsutsuki chakra, and
>   detonating the orb if needed.